# Ruby Kernel.raise method throws error when enclosing parameters in parenthesis

Tags: ruby, parentheses, raise

I like method parameters enclosed in parenthesis, this is some Pascal nostalgia. When cleaning up code, if I find a method parameters without it I enclose them immediately.
Today it caused my working code throwing errors although my syntax looks okay according to the documentation.

Kernel.raise's documentation has this format:

```
(Object) raise(exception[, string [, array]])
```

These are all working:

```
> raise TypeError
TypeError: TypeError

> raise (TypeError)
TypeError: TypeError

> raise "Error message"
RuntimeError: Error message

> raise ("Error message")
RuntimeError: Error message
```

But the enclosed version of the next throws syntax error:

```
> raise TypeError, "Error message"
TypeError: Error message

> raise (TypeError, "Error message")
SyntaxError: unexpected ')', expecting $end
```

I can live without it, I just want to know why this ends with an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably already know that in idiomatic Ruby one would never insert a space between the end of a method and an argument list in parenthesis. [Some](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) style guides [explicitly forbid it](http://rubyist.info/style/).

There's a pragmatic reason too.

```
1.9.2-p290 > def concat(a, b)
1.9.2-p290 >  a + b
1.9.2-p290 > end

1.9.2-p290 > concat 'foo', 'bar'
 => "foobar"
1.9.2-p290 > concat('foo', 'bar')
 => "foobar"
1.9.2-p290 > concat ('foo', 'bar')
SyntaxError: (irb):27: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
```

You'll encounter errors calling any method this way, not just `Kernel.raise`.

I'm not familiar with Ruby internals, but I would imagine the reason for this is that when a space precedes the argument list, Ruby is expecting the "no-parens" style. So of course this works:

```
1.9.2-p290 :035 > concat ("bar"), ("foo")
 => "barfoo"
```

Presumably Ruby is trying to evaluate the contents of each parenthesized expression before passing the result to the method. I'd speculate that writing `raise (TypeError, "Error message")` is asking Ruby to evaluate just `TypeError, "Error message"`, which of course fails.

Answer (score 3):

Parentheses are used for expression grouping and precedence override in Ruby. So, when you say

```
foo (bar, baz)
```

You are sending the message `:foo` with a single argument which is the result of evaluating the expression `bar, baz`. And `bar, baz` is not a valid expression, therefore you get a `SyntaxError`.

```
foo (bar)
```

works, because `bar` is a valid expression.

```
foo (if bar then baz else quux end)
```

would work, too.

If you want Ruby to interpret parentheses not for expression grouping but for passing multiple arguments along with a message send, the opening parenthesis needs to directly follow the message selector:

```
foo(bar, baz)
```

This has nothing to do with `Kernel#raise`, BTW. You cannot change the syntax for message sends in Ruby (in fact, you cannot change *any* syntax in Ruby), therefore whatever is true for `Kernel#raise` must also be true for every other method.